# SQL hierarchical query up to 10 level

Tags: sql-server, hierarchical-query

I want to write a SQL Server `SELECT` query to display data in hierarchical in tabular format.

Like: employee reports to X manager, then X manager reports to XX manager, and then XX manager reports to XXX manager - for each line of record.

Table data:

[Input data format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdhtT.jpg)

Output format:

[output required format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atdVY.jpg)

Comment: Do you want pure SQL or is some programming language involved?

Comment: @Niklaus- pure sql

Comment: Depending on your input data this might be solveable with a recursice CTE... Please do not poste pictures! Please tag with the actual RDBMS (product and version) and please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Simple, join 10 virtual tables together

```
Select person, Person1, Person2, ...
from people
left join
    (
    select person as Person1, Manager as Manager2 from People
    ) as People1
        on people.Manager = Person1
left join
    (
    select person as Person2, Manager as Manager3 from People
    ) as People2
        on Manager2 = Person2
....
```

Comment: @JeffUk-thanks...its takes some time for 70K records, but its ok.